# android adding fragment programatically doesn't accept parameter

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to add a fragment programatically to my layout in the `MainActivity`, to be more specific in its `onCreate` method. I keep getting an error `Cannot resolve method add()`, and that really shouldnt happen because I've copied the code from the official site. Somebody please help. Here is the code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        FooterVertical fragment = new FooterVertical();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

public class FooterVertical extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FooterVertical() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FooterVertical newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FooterVertical fragment = new FooterVertical();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer_vertical, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes, multiple times but it didn't help

Comment: Can you also show your FooterVertical fragment and xml layout file code?

Comment: change the import from "import android.app.Fragment;" to "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;"

Comment: Thank you my friend, now it is good. You re a life saver :)

Comment: @zomlaaa95 Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing `android.app.Fragment;` change it to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```